# Non-Webkit Browsers not showing special characters correctly

Tags: html, css, webkit, special-characters, google-font-api

I use Google Web Fonts in my project, and I got a strange issue. Everything works fine in Chrome, Mobile Safari, Mobile Chrome, and even Android Browser, but in non-webkit browsers (IE11, Latest FF) special characters (in my case "ğ,Ğ") not showing in standard font.

Here's the font imports:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allura);

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [instructed by Google](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Allura), you need to request for support to “Latin Extended” in order to get all the Turkish letters right. Instead of

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allura);
```

use

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allura&subset=latin,latin-ext);
```

Similarly for other fonts.